# Given point/value pairs for the vertices of a tetrahedron, how do you get values for other points inside the tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, interpolation, finite-element-method, barycentric-coordinates

We will look at the 3 dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Say we have a tetrahedron with the vertices $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, and $p_4$, each with corresponding value $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, and $v_4$. Given a point P inside the tetrahedron (could also be on a face), how would one calculate the corresponding value of P?

I tried interpolating in some way but I'm a little too inexperienced on that side.
Also tried to use a hyperplane running through the 4 points, but this also leads nowhere for me.

Comment: How would one get these coeficients? Is there some general way that works for every tetrahedron?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  for the convex body and interior it should be $a_i \geq 0$    and $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 1 $

Comment: Are you specifically trying to interpolate linearly? The "corresponding value" isn't defined at the moment.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, of course: I mistakenly wrote $0$ instead of $1$, sorry!

Comment: I deleted my comments above for clarity. The corrected hint is that $=_1_1+_2_2+_3_3+_4_4$, where $_$ are real numbers adding up to $1$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  the $a_i$   must be non-negative, all $0 \leq a_i \leq 1 .$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, if $P$ is inside the tetrahedron then all $a_i\in[0,1]$. But the decomposition works for any $P$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca It worked great, thank you very much!

Comment: The name of the $a_i$ is ["tetrahedron coordinates"](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/nentchev/node31.html) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ (generalization of the "barycentric coordinates" in the plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want linear interpolation. First you express $P$ as a linear combination of the vertices in such a way that the coefficients add up to $1$.

$$
a_1p_1+a_2p_2+a_3p_3+a_4p_4=P\\
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=1
$$

You can combine these into a single matrix equation:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\\
y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4\\
z_1&z_2&z_3&z_4\\
1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now you can employ the standard tools for solving systems of linear equations to get the $a_i$.

Then you use those coefficients to combine values, too.

$$v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3+a_4v_4$$

Note that as long as your point $P$ lies inside the tetrahedron, you get $0\lt a_i\lt 1$. On the boundary you get some equalities. And outside you get some negative numbers and may exceed $1$ to compensate.